# Regarding the approach of displaying a classification/decision tree from the command line?

Tags: weka, decision-tree

In Weka, how to display a classification/decision tree from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking for something very elaborated, but basically decision trees are printed when you use [weka.classifiers.trees](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/trees/package-summary.html). There is an illustration with Random Tree in a [response of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042994/420055), but here is what you would get using the `J48` algorithm on the iris dataset:

```
~/weka/data$ weka weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t iris.arff  -i

J48 pruned tree
------------------

petalwidth <= 0.6: Iris-setosa (50.0)
petalwidth > 0.6
|   petalwidth <= 1.7
|   |   petallength <= 4.9: Iris-versicolor (48.0/1.0)
|   |   petallength > 4.9
|   |   |   petalwidth <= 1.5: Iris-virginica (3.0)
|   |   |   petalwidth > 1.5: Iris-versicolor (3.0/1.0)
|   petalwidth > 1.7: Iris-virginica (46.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     5

Size of the tree :  9


Time taken to build model: 0.08 seconds
Time taken to test model on training data: 0.01 seconds
```